# How to set text as bold and italics based on Markdown text input

Tags: google-apps-script, markdown, google-docs

Essentially I'm looking for a way to process Markdown-style text to automagically use the [.setBold(), .setItalic(), and .setUnderline() methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setBold(Boolean)) to modify the text being added to a Google Doc.

I am working on a script that reads text from a cells in Google Sheet and creates a Google Doc. (The text in the sheet originally came from a Google Form.)

I want entries such as `Certain words are **bold**, *italicized*, or a ***combination*** thereof.` to appear as:

> Certain words are **bold**, *italicized*, or a ***combination*** thereof.

... in the final Google Doc that is created. Ideally, I'd like the option to `_underline_` as well.

Comment: Would you want to set the style before inserting text in the doc or after text has already been inserted? The approach would be completely different.

Comment: The current implementation would be most compatible with setting style BEFORE inserting text. Though, I can adapt if after proves more natural.